# Jasmine Testing for ExtJS 6.6

Tags: extjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to Unit Test, an Ext JS application using Jasmine directly instead of Sencha Test(Sencha Product) which is also using Jasmine in the core.

While writing the specs of it.

```
 describe("A suite", function() {
  var mainView = null;
  beforeEach(function() {
      mainView = Ext.create('LoginApp.view.main.login.LoginViewController');
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
      expect(mainView != null).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am getting this error

> ReferenceError: Ext is not defined.

Please suggest what I am missing here. Rest in case of any doubt feel free to ask, I will add the required information.

Comment: Pretty much as it says. Ext isn't being included when you run Jasmine.

Comment: thanks, @EvanTrimboli, where and how to add it then? Any tutorial for the configuration set up?

Comment: For ExtJS 6.6 and Jasmine 3.3

Comment: Do you use the SpecRunner.html of jasmine? Can you share it here?

Comment: @And-y, No I am not using it. I found one git repo claiming to use Jasmine 2.6.4 with ExtJS 6.5 https://github.com/rcogal/extjs-jasmine and I am following it and it is not using SpecRunner.html but I am still not succeeded. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue above?